# jQuery Script - Toggle open / close with specific script?

Tags: jquery

I am currently using the following jQuery script: http://davidwalsh.name/twitter-dropdown-jquery -- I am having one specific issue. The following jQuery script is similar to that of Twitter's login, it toggles a div. However, with this script I can't toggle out of the div (either by clicking out of the box or the text that is is assigned to open it). I have attached the code, and I am pretty sure the end of the code deals with this issue, I am just unsure of how to change it so that it doesn't destroy the script. I want for users to be able to just click the link that toggles it open to toggle it closed when they are done. If anyone could help that would be great!

I can't seem to post the entire jQuery script here but I included a link to where the code is available for view.

Comment: The code is the exact same code that is found here: http://davidwalsh.name/twitter-dropdown-jquery -- I tried to post the entire jQuery script but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: There must be some difference if it works there but it doesn't work for you. :) Can you try setting it up on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: It works, I just want to change the code slightly so that when the user clicks the text that toggles it on it will toggle it off (if open). Right now if you click outside of the area it toggles it off, and I am not exactly like that. -- Here is a link on jsfiddle.net: http://jsfiddle.net/Hzq4E/

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post, I thought it was not working as expected.

Comment: That's okay! If anyone with more expertise than myself could maybe modify this jQuery script to do what I am looking for it to do that would be amazing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around in JsFiddle for a while I've come up with some code that does what you want, I've tried to change as little of the existing code as possible.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  /* for keeping track of what's "open" */
  var activeClass = 'dropdown-active',
      focusFired = false,                
      showingDropdown, showingMenu, showingParent; 
  /* hides the current menu */
  var hideMenu = function() {
      if (showingDropdown) {
        showingDropdown.removeClass(activeClass);
        showingDropdown = null;
        showingMenu.hide();
    }
  };

  /* recurse through dropdown menus */
  $('.dropdown').each(function() { /* track elements: menu, parent */
    var dropdown = $(this);
    var menu = dropdown.next('div.dropdown-menu'),
        parent = dropdown.parent(); /* function that shows THIS menu */
    var showMenu = function() {
        hideMenu();
        showingDropdown = dropdown.addClass('dropdown-active');
        showingMenu = menu.show();
        showingParent = parent;
    }; 

    /* function to toggle menu when clicked */
    dropdown.bind('click', function(e) {
        console.log('Click fired');
        if (e) e.stopPropagation();
        if (e) e.preventDefault();
        if(showingDropdown == dropdown && !focusFired) {
            hideMenu();
        } else {
            showMenu();
        }
        focusFired = false;
    }); 
    /* function to show menu when someone tabs to the box */
    dropdown.bind('focus', function() {
        focusFired = true;
        showMenu();
    });
  });

  /* hide when clicked outside */
  $(document.body).bind('click', function(e) {
    if (showingParent) {
        var parentElement = showingParent[0];
        if (!$.contains(parentElement, e.target) || !parentElement == e.target) {
            hideMenu();
        }
    }
  });
});
```

There are some things that are non-obvious at first, when you click into an element a focus event fires and a click event fires, since focus shows the menu you can't just check the state there because it will show and quickly hide the menu.  That's why I added a focusFired flag that the click event checks before hiding.

Answer (score 2):

You can change just a tiny bit of code:

```
/* function to show menu when clicked */
dropdown.bind('click',function(e) {
  if(e) e.stopPropagation();
  if(e) e.preventDefault();
  if(menu.is(':visible'){
    hideMenu();
  } else {
    showMenu();
  }
});
```

Let me know if it works, as it's completely untested.

**Edit:** Check out @ihumanable's answer, he cared to actually test the code before asking for any feedback. :)